# How powerful is the dua Yastasheer?

Tags: allah, dua

I heard that the [dua Yastasheer](http://www.qul.org.au/library/duas-supplications/402-dua-yastasheer-the-supplication-of-yastasheer) is a very powerful Dua and if you recite it 3 times there is nothing that Allah won't grant of your wishes in this life and the hereafter. Has anyone else heard this? And have anyone witness this from their own experience work?

Comment: Every dua is powerful but a person only needs intentioned to be right.

Comment: Where did you get this dua from? Your sources pls...

Comment: Oh sorry I just sheared up " very powerful duas " and found it on google

Comment: Why don't you recite it 3 times yourself and let us know if your wishes were granted?

Comment: I did for the past 3 nights and it works amazingly  Alhamdulillah !

Answer (score 1):

There has mentioned a lot regarding the reward(Thawab) of this Dua, but at the moment I explain solely concerning the mentioned reward that you asked.

**The apostle of Allah (pbuh) said:**

> **Whoever recites this Dua three times, Allah will give all of his/her
>   good(خیر) wishes.**

Or another tradition form Imam Ali (a.s.) (that Seyyed ibn Tawus quoted):

> The apostle of Allah taught me (this Dua) and ordered me to recite it in each hardness or easiness and likewise I teach it to my
>   successor and do not leave reciting of this Dua till…

So, to be honest, I have not read this Dua before, but I am sure that in case of the accuracy of this tradition, you ought to be sure that it will give you its mentioned rewards. But there is a point that you have to pay attention...

Actually observing the conditions of Dua(to be answered) will help you reach your wishes. In truth, as you are aware, there are some factors that you ought to observe them(beside the Dua), otherwise there is no warranty that Allah answer your wishes.

So, I recommend you to search for the conditions of Dua (what conditions shall we observe as well as reciting that). Since I reckon there must be many people that recite some Duas, but they don’t reach their wishes. so, reasonably, it is related to its conditions as well.

Anyhow, for more info. about its Thawab, you can refer to the book below:

> (Mhj al Da'awat) مهج الدعوات
>
> You can download it through the link below:
>
> ([www.sarbazaneislam.com](http://www.sarbazaneislam.com/ketab-mohajodaavat-seyyedebntavoos.html)
>   )

A part of Dua (Yastasheer):

بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ 
 ‏
الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ الَّذِي لا إِلَهَ إِلا هُوَ الْمَلِكُ الْحَقُّ الْمُبِينُ الْمُدَبِّرُ بِلا وَزِيرٍ وَ لا خَلْقٍ مِنْ عِبَادِهِ يَسْتَشِيرُ الْأَوَّلُ غَيْرُ مَوْصُوفٍ [مَصْرُوفٍ‏] وَ الْبَاقِي بَعْدَ فَنَاءِ الْخَلْقِ الْعَظِيمُ الرُّبُوبِيَّةِ نُورُ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَ الْأَرَضِينَ [الْأَرْضِ‏] وَ فَاطِرُهُمَا وَ مُبْتَدِعُهُمَا بِغَيْرِ عَمَدٍ خَلَقَهُمَا وَ فَتَقَهُمَا فَتْقا فَقَامَتِ السَّمَاوَاتُ طَائِعَاتٍ بِأَمْرِهِ وَ اسْتَقَرَّتِ الْأَرَضُونَ بِأَوْتَادِهَا فَوْقَ الْمَاءِ ثُمَّ عَلا رَبُّنَا فِي السَّمَاوَاتِ الْعُلَى الرَّحْمَنُ عَلَى الْعَرْشِ اسْتَوَى لَهُ مَا فِي السَّمَاوَاتِ وَ مَا فِي الْأَرْضِ وَ مَا بَيْنَهُمَا وَ مَا تَحْتَ الثَّرَی

---

**Sources:**

[www.imamatjome.com](http://www.imamatjome.com/Sermons/SermonsShow.aspx?Id=41410&AId=144)

[www.erfan.ir/farsi](http://www.erfan.ir/farsi/mafatih45/)